# Difference between git reset commands

Tags: git

I have been using `git reset --soft HEAD^` and `git reset --soft HEAD~1` when I want to return my last commit to the staging area.  I have been using them interchangeably but was wondering if there were any subtle differences? If there aren't any, can you explain the syntactical difference?  Is `^` just an alias for `~1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HEAD^` and `HEAD~1` refer to the same commit.

`^` refers to the first parent of the commit. `~n` refers to the n:th ancestor. So `^^` (parent-of-parent) is equivalent to `~2`.

The main subtlety I can think of is if there is several parents to the current commit (i.e. it is a merge commit). In that case both `HEAD^` and `HEAD^2` are valid and refer to different commits. `HEAD~1` refers to `HEAD^` but not `HEAD^2`

The [gitrevisions man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) has lots of details and examples.

Answer (score 2):

Even though `HEAD^` and `HEAD~1` do the same thing, they mean slightly different things. `HEAD^` is shorthand for `HEAD^1`, which references commit's first parent and `HEAD^2` would refer to the commit's second parent. `HEAD~` is shorthand for `HEAD~1`, which references the commit's first parent and `HEAD~2` references the commit's first parent's first parent. These two syntaxes are interchangeable unless the `HEAD` is a merge commit, in which case it can have more than one parent (the previous commit on the master branch and the previous commit on the branch that was merged into master).

Comment: It’s the other way around though: `HEAD^X` is the Xth parent, and `HEAD~X` is the commit X times before.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `HEAD~1` is used for a linear history whereas the `HEAD^` is able to follow commits with multiple parents.

Answer (score 1):

HEAD^ and HEAD~1 are the same thing.

From my notes:

*ref*^ means the commit before *ref*.  Multiple ^ characters can be used. Example:  HEAD^^^

*ref*~n means the nth commit before *ref*. Example: HEAD~3

There are more complicated forms that allow you to deal with the case where your base reference (e.g. HEAD) is the result of a merge.

Actually, it can get *really* complicated. See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html

Answer (score 0):

No, `HEAD^` and `HEAD~1` (as well as `HEAD~` or `HEAD^1`) refer to the same commit.

Adding a `^` or `~` after something that describes to a commit will both change the reference to the first parent of the commit described by the preceding portion of the argument.

The difference comes in when a number follows the symbol. If no number is given, it works the same as if `1` was used.

A number following a `^` selects which of the parents of a merge commit should be used (somewhat like choosing the father or mother). The first parent would be the commit which was checked out when the merge commit was created, the other parents would be commits named with the `git merge` command.

A number following a `~` refers to the  number of generations to go back (following the first parent relationship at every step), 1 to the immediate parent, 2 to the grand-parent and so on.

These notations can also be chained such as `HEAD~3^2~5`, although it would usually be simpler to just use a SHA1 ID to refer to commits which would need that type of notation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have commited to your local repo already (ie. git commit -m ) then you can reverse that last commit by doing **git reset --soft HEAD ~1**
  If you have staged your changes already (ie with  git add .) then you can reverse the staging by doing **git reset --mixed HEAD**
  and **git reset --hard** wipes everything out (even your local changes). The ~ after head tells you how many commits to go to from the top.